# VBA: Export more than one column to txt

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to export several columns of data in excel - with blank cells in them - to a single one - without blanks - into a .txt file.
So far, I have assembled some pieces of code and I can export ONE column with success.
What I'm hoping to do is to copy/paste one column below the one before and so on into the .txt without blanks.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim r As Range, c As Range, rng As Range
Dim sTemp As String
Dim UnusedColumn As Range
Dim Filename As String

Filename = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\xxx.txt"
Open Filename For Output As #1
Set rng = Range("A2:A1000")

'Find a column with nothing in it
  Set UnusedColumn = Cells.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).EntireColumn.Offset(0, 15)

'Create temporary calculation column to determine which cells to select (marked by an X)
  Intersect(rng.EntireRow, UnusedColumn) = Evaluate("IF(" & rng.Address & "="""","""",""X"")")

'Make Selection
  Intersect(UnusedColumn.SpecialCells(xlConstants).EntireRow, rng.EntireColumn).Select

'Remove Temporary Blank Caluclations
  UnusedColumn.Clear

For Each r In Selection
    sTemp = ""
    For Each c In r.Cells
        sTemp = sTemp & c.Text & Chr(9)
    Next c

    'Get rid of trailing tabs
    While Right(sTemp, 1) = Chr(9)
        sTemp = Left(sTemp, Len(sTemp) - 1)
    Wend
    Print #1, sTemp
Next r
Close #1
End Sub
```

There's some instructions in there to automatically select non-blank cells and to export each row without quotation marks.

Here's how the .txt looks like with the original code (one column):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DiB33.jpg

And here's how the columns look like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Tn3m.jpg

Sorry for the unpolished english and code.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you iterate over an array using a `For Each Loop` the VBA iterates each element by columns (all the elements in the 1st column, then all the elements in the second column...etc.).

It took 2.38 Second to write 10,000 rows x 255 columns with %50 populated with 14 Digit numbers stored as text

```
Sub WriteToValues()
    Dim Start: Start = Timer
    Dim Data, v
    Dim FileName As String
    FileName = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\xxx.txt"

    Data = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value2

    Open FileName For Output As #1

    For Each v In Data
        If v <> vbNullString Then Print #1, CStr(v)
    Next

    Close #1
    Debug.Print Timer - Start
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: This is great, Thomas! Mind if I ask another question? Let say i want to have a A2:D1000 range... how can I solve that?
Thanks!

Comment: Go ahead. Shoot away

Comment: Let say i want to have a A2:D1000 range... how can I solve that? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry about that I was on my phone.  If you want to use `[A2:D1000]` as the range then change `Data = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value2` to `Data = Range("A2:D1000").Value2`.

Comment: Perfect. Man, you're the best. I'm feeling like a Neardenthal right now. Thanks, dude.

Comment: You should watch "The Wise Owl Tutorials" on Youtube: [Excel VBA Introduction](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KHO5NIcZAc4&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5)